# Android device >4.3 doesnt fire ng-show validations on Ionic App

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am currently building an Ionic App and testing it out with genymotion emulator and I found out an issue.

With Android devices that  is 4.3 and below, my ng-show expressions work fine and show when need to and hide when need to but if the Android device is >4.3 i.e. 4.4.2 nd so son... All ng-show expressions do not fire or do not catch at all.

I dont know if anyone has encountered an issue like this before or if anyone has a good theory why this is happening.

Thanks

Comment: Hmm i am using Ionic for an app and i use too ng-show. My device is 5.0.2 and ng-show works ...

Comment: No problems here, maybe share some code and perhaps we can help